# I can't read image with open-cv from bytes

Tags: python, opencv, flask

Hey guys help me please.

I have flask rest api that receive multipart/form-data as image and I want to use opencv to process it .

My problem is I can't read image with cv2.imdecode.

This function is return none so what's wrong.

```
imgFile = request.files['image']
imgBuffer = imgFile.read() # <class 'bytes'>
#b'\xc3\xbf\xc3\x98\xc3\xbf\xc3\xa0\x00\x10'

img = np.frombuffer(imgBuffer, dtype='uint8') # <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
#[195 191 195 152 195 191 195 160   0  16]

img = cv2.imdecode(img, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR) # <class 'NoneType'>
```

[image: My image is here]

Comment: can u add a example image

Comment: I already uploaded it.

Answer (score 1):

`cv2.imdecode()` expects to decode a JPEG-encoded or PNG-encoded image. Such an image would start with:

- the JPEG signature `ff d8 ff` or
- the PNG signature `89 50 4e 47 0d 0a 1a 0a`

Yours does not. So it is probably just the raw, unencoded pixels and you probably just need:

```
img = np.array(imgBuffer).reshape((height,width))
```

---

Another clue is the size of your `bytes` buffer. If its size matches the height x width of your greyscale image (or 3x that if colour) it means your image is just pixel data, whereas you would expect a JPEG/PNG encoded image to be much smaller because it's compressed.

Comment: My image size is 650 × 457 (297050) but buffer length I got is 121640. So this is mean my image is already encoded right??

Comment: I already reshaped it but I it throw me an error --> Can't not reshape 121640 to height * width

Comment: @BunpotDarawankul So you'd need to show the code that wrote the data into the file you are reading so we can see how it was compressed or encoded or created. And also share the actual file you are reading - probably using Dropbox or Google Drive or some other binary file sharing service.

Comment: multipart/form-data in body. I not work on lambda but It work on localhost.

Answer (score 1):

Try making the following changes to your code.

```
imgFile = request.files['image']
imgBuffer = imgFile.read() # <class 'bytes'>
#b'\xc3\xbf\xc3\x98\xc3\xbf\xc3\xa0\x00\x10'
my_img = cv2.imread(imgFile, 0)
my_img.imshow(my_img)
#stream = io.StringIO(imgBuffer.decode("UTF8"), newline=None)

#img = np.frombuffer(stream, dtype='uint8') # <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
#[195 191 195 152 195 191 195 160   0  16]

#img = cv2.imdecode(img, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR) # <class 'NoneType'>
```

Comment: I got this --> typeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'

Comment: I have made some new changes to the answer, try using this code.

Comment: I got --> TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not '_io.StringIO'

Comment: I think np.frombuffer expected a bytes object only

Comment: Why dont you try to use imread() and other such function here instead of np.frombuffer? That might ease. I will make some changes in code for you to try those functions.

Comment: Because my function will receive image from http and I test it through postman. I got image data as bytes.